# Ignoring @AfterMethod call when using groups in TestNG.xml

Tags: java, testing, testng

I have a test which has the following code:

```java
public class ViewLineList 
{

Browser browser = new Browser();
WebDriver driver;

public void viewLineList(String driverName)
{
    driver = browser.getDriver(driverName);
    
    //Navigate to System Facing
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.navigate().to("URL GOES HERE");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //Verify Line List is present
    WebElement lineList = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/form/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div"));
    Assert.assertNotNull(lineList, "The Line List is empty");
    Assert.assertEquals(true, lineList.isDisplayed(), "The line list is not displayed");
        
    //Verify Columns are present
    
    WebElement poEligibleColumn = driver.findElement(By.linkText("PO Eligible"));
    WebElement patientColumn = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Patient/SSN"));
    WebElement wardColumn = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Ward/Room"));
    WebElement drugColumn = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Drug"));
    WebElement dosageColumn = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Dosage"));
    WebElement startDateColumn = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Start Date"));
    WebElement nextDoseColumn = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Next Dose"));
    WebElement lastReviewDateColumn = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Last Review Date"));
    WebElement reviewerColumn = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Reviewer"));
    WebElement toolsColumn  = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Tools"));
    
    Assert.assertEquals(true, poEligibleColumn.isDisplayed(), "The PO Eligible column is not present");
    Assert.assertEquals(true, patientColumn.isDisplayed(), "The Patient column is not present");
    Assert.assertEquals(true, wardColumn.isDisplayed(), "The Ward column is not present");
    Assert.assertEquals(true, drugColumn.isDisplayed(), "The Drug column is not present");
    Assert.assertEquals(true, dosageColumn.isDisplayed(), "The Dosage column is not present");
    Assert.assertEquals(true, startDateColumn.isDisplayed(), "The Start Date column is not present");
    Assert.assertEquals(true, nextDoseColumn.isDisplayed(), "The Next Dose column is not present");
    Assert.assertEquals(true, lastReviewDateColumn.isDisplayed(), "The Last Review Date column is not present");
    Assert.assertEquals(true, reviewerColumn.isDisplayed(), "The Reviewer column is not present");
    Assert.assertEquals(true, toolsColumn.isDisplayed(), "The Tools column is not present");
}
```

Tests - Run these

```java
@Test(groups = {"functionalTests.FF"})
public void test_ViewLineList_FF() 
{
    viewLineList("firefox");
}
    
@Test(groups = {"functionalTests.IE"})
public void test_ViewLineList_IE() 
{
    viewLineList("ie");
}
@AfterMethod
public void tearDown()
{
    driver.quit();
}
```

The `@AfterMethod` is working fine when I run the test from the class above. The problem comes in when I call the class from my TestNG.xml. Which is below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
  <test name="Test" preserve-order="true">
    <groups>
      <run>
        <include name="functionalTests.FF"/>
        <exclude name="functionalTests.IE"/>
        <exclude name="functionalTests.iOS"/>    
      </run>
    </groups> 
    <classes>
      <class name="ui_Tests.ViewLineList"/> 
      <!-- <class name="ui_Tests.ViewLineListResolutions"/>
      <class name="ui_Tests.InteractWithLineList"/> 
      <class name="ui_Tests.POEligibleTests"/> 
      <class name="ui_Tests.DisableColumns"/> 
      <class name="ui_Tests.ExpandCollapseBars"/> 
      <class name="ui_Tests.BarGraphs"/> -->
    </classes>    
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

If I run the test from the XML file then the `@AfterMethod` is ignored. I have likewise tried `@AfterTest` and `@AfterClass` and they all seem to be ignored when the test fails.

Comment: They should be run no matter what..are you sure they are not executed? Have you tried adding some logging just to be sure?

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg Well, the `@AfterMethod` et al, should run regardless of pass/fail condition, which means that the web browser should be closing. It is not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `@AfterMethod` is not run because it's not in the group that you're running.
You have either specify the group or tell it to always run.

```
@AfterMethod(groups = {"functionalTests.FF"})
```

or

```
@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
```

Most likely you want to use `alwaysRun = true`.